# Timing a method and threads in .NET

Tags: c#, multithreading, timing, frame-rate

I have two threads in my app - the main UI thread and another thread initiated by the wm_WiiMoteChanged event handler (a background thread). In the main thread I do some video processing. I have a function called `processFrame` shown below. I use that code to measure the time to process each frame and thus the frames per second rate.

If I comment out the `wm.WiiMoteChanged ...` line (see below), the frame rates are about 15-20 fps and looking at the video, this seems right (there is a small lag).

But when I uncomment the line, i.e. add the event handler (which will spawn a thread on its own), the fps goes up to 40-50, but this is definitely wrong - the video is in fact more laggy.

Can someone explain to me why this happens? Thanks.

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        wm.Connect();
        //wm.WiimoteChanged += wm_WiimoteChanged; 

        wm.SetReportType(InputReport.IRAccel, true);
        wm.SetLEDs(false, false, false, true);
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + x.Message);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

More code:

```
private void processFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime curr = DateTime.Now;
    performOperation();
    TimeSpan currTime = DateTime.Now - curr;
    lblFPS.Text = (1000 / currTime.Milliseconds).ToString() + " fps";
}
```

**EDIT**

An interesting find, only when this line is present in wm_WiimoteChanged, does this happen.

`ibxOutput.Image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(_irViewAreaBitmap);`

*Sidenote:* this line is the cause of the higher lag too - the processing done before setting this is actually fast!

Comment: Do you mean *If I comment out the `wm.WiiMoteChanged` ...*. Because *don't comment* and *uncomment* sound the same...???

Comment: can you paste the code of your `wm_WiimoteChanged` method?

Comment: @dboarman: haha, fixed the "don't comment" to "comment". Thanks

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Because by adding a event handler, you are responding to those `WiimoteChanged`  events and running extra code.</strike>

Does the handler contain locking? Suggest you post the code for `wm_WiimoteChanged()`

UPDATE: Suggest you use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` rather than `DateTime.Now` It is likely that DateTime.Now is not accurate enough.

Comment: He's asking why his reported FPS is going UP, even though it's taking longer per frame...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I get similar results using StopWatch. The FPS is higher with the event handler added (in particular, setting the image property of the image box inside the event handler).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm being thick here, but I don't understand the frames per second calculation?

Should your FPS not actually be the number of times that `ProcessFrame` is called in a second?  If you measure that you might get a more accurate result.

Also, for measuring time, you're better off using `StopWatch`; it's built for this purpose.

Comment: @Neil: I guess I could do that. I just found this much easier, 1000 ms divided by the milliseconds to process a single frame = number of frames that can be processed in one second. And about StopWatch, I tried it, I get similar results :(

Answer (score 0):

Does exactly one frame get rendered to the screen for each invocation of the `processFrame` method?  I suspect the rendering is happening elsewhere and is blocked by the code in the `WiimoteChanged` handler, giving your `processFrame` method more processor time.

For your FPS measurement to be accurate you need to ensure that `processFrame` is called exactly once per frame.  You should probably measure the time between subsequent invocations too rather than measuring the duration of `performOperation`, unless `processFrame` will be called immediately again when it returns.